# How to fetch data from mysql database on the basis of key value in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to fetch the data from MySQL database on the basis of key-value as shown in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTKv2.png).
 I am trying to implement like

```
    $msg_query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "setting WHERE code = 'apply_checkout'");
```

[image]

Comment: Please include the data from the image into your actual question. Furthermore, please include some more of the relevant information: for example what's the value of `DB_PREFIX` and what results/errors are you getting with your current setup? Also checkout https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. With that all done, I am sure people would be glad/able to help you out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `foreach()`

```
foreach ($msg_query as $row) 
{
    print $row['setting_id'] . "\t";
    print $row['store_id'] . "\t";
    print $row['key'] . "\t";
    print $row['value'] . "\t";
    print $row['serialized'] . "\n";
}
```

This code will print the result.
So you can access data inside the loop